# Setting the correct height of a UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'm trying to return the height of the `detailTextLabel` in the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method. This way my table view cells should be the same height as my `detailTextLabel`.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *text = cell.detailTextLabel.text;
    CGSize size = cell.detailTextLabel.bounds.size;
    UIFont *font = cell.detailTextLabel.font;

    CGSize labelSize = [text sizeWithFont:font                           
                        constrainedToSize:size
                            lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    return labelSize.height;
}
```

However I'm getting a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on the following line:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Wats wrong with the above piece of code?

Comment: `-tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` is called during `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` so when you call `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, the cell has not been fully created yet, so you can't reference it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access cell.textLabel.text in tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903136/how-to-access-cell-textlabel-text-in-tableviewheightforrowatindexpath-from-tab) and many, many others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is called before `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.  So the cell has not been created yet.

If all rows have the same height you can specify a common height for the table.  In your `viewDidLoad` you can just say `self.tableView.rowHeight = ABC;`  You can also set this in Interface builder.

Answer (score 2):

This

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

should be

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

But this will result into several calls of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, better approach: Write a helper method, that calculates the hight for each indexPath, call it from `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, save the heigh save the height in a dictionary with indexpathes as keys and only calculate the height, id a indexPath is not present (or some how needs to be recalculated). Return the height.